# Update docs or Insert with update_by_query API in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Looking for API which Update or Insert depending on record present in ES.

I have tried using update_by_query, but it is not creating any record if it doesn't exist.

```
POST track_index/track_type/_update_by_query
{"query": {"bool":
      {"must": [{"match_phrase": {"tracking_id": 219215}}, 
        {"match_phrase": {"order_id": 5401759}}]}}, 
    "script": {"lang": "painless", 
        "inline": """ctx._source['loction']='IN';
                    ctx._source['tracking_id']=219215;
                    ctx._source['order_id']=5401759;
                     ctx._source['path']='/tmp'"""
}
}
```

Is there a way around which will search and update a record if exists or create a new entry

Comment: What would the `_id` of your document be? The `tracking_id`?

Comment: Update by `tracking_id` and `order_id` but create with `_id`

Comment: Yes, and what value do you give to `_id`?

Comment: I don't want to give any value..It should be auto generated one likewise every new entry

Comment: If the id was made up by the `tracking_id` and the `order_id`, the solution would be easy. That combination is unique, right?

Comment: @Sandy Did you manage to get the use-case working?